# Showing there is a solution to a particular pair of polynomials over finite fields.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to show over any prime order field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p\geq 11$, that the following pair of equations has at least one solution for any choice of $a$ and $b$ where $b$ is non-square, excluding obvious $a,b$ when the curves become degenerate.

\begin{cases}
      x^4-4x^3+2x^2y^2+4x^2y+16x^2-4xy^2+24xy+8x+y^4+4y^3+16y^2-8y=4b-4\\
      (x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=2a+4
    \end{cases}

They seem pretty well behaved as curves, one is just a circle (when its not degenerate) and the other seems to be smooth except for a few values of $b$ like $b=4$ (I haven't done the full calculation yet, thats just the obvious singularity). But I don't know how to show that a solution should always exist, or how to construct a counterexample. I have currently checked that its true for $p\leq 101$.

Comment: Probably the term $+4x^3$ is $+4y^3$  and the last $+$ just before the equality sign is superfluous.

Comment: @MCipu Yes thanks typo fixed.